# Combine 2D numpy arrays with random separating line

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have two 2D NumPy arrays with the same shape:

```
>>> a.shape
(100, 100)
>>> b.shape
(100, 100)
```

I'm using these in a genetic algorithm and would like to implement [crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm)). My thought is to pick a random separating line, taking `a` on one side and `b` on the other.

The line would be the one going through `pt` and `pt + delta`:

```py
pt = np.random.uniform(a.shape)
angle = np.random.uniform(0, math.pi)
delta = np.array([math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)])
```

How can I create a new array that's equal to `a` above this line and equal to `b` below it? A hard dividing line is fine, but for bonus points a blend of the two for pixels on the line would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing an idea with helper arrays, using a simple linear function:

```
# helper arrays for coordinate system
x = np.ones((100,100))
x[:,:] = np.arange(100)

y = np.ones((100,100))
y[:,:] = 100-np.arange(100).reshape(100,1) # 100- to invert y-axis

# linear function
def linfunc(x, m, n):
    return x*m + n
```

The idea is to call a linear transformation on the `x` coordinates, and then check where the result is equal to, smaller, or larger than the `y` coordinates. The result of this assertion can then be used to index the input images.

```
#test data:
a = np.ones((100,100))
b = np.zeros((100,100)) + 2
ab_mean = (a+b)/2
```

Test cases:

```
test_line = linfunc(x, 1, 0) #  y = x 
output = np.zeros_like(a)
output[y>test_line] = a[y>test_line] # assign above line to a
output[y<test_line] = b[y<test_line] # assign below line to b
output[y==test_line] = ab_mean[y==test_line] # assign coords on line to "interpolation"
plt.imshow(output)
```

[image]

```
test_line = linfunc(x, 1, 10) #  y = x + 10
output = np.zeros_like(a)
output[y>test_line] = a[y>test_line] # assign above line to a
output[y<test_line] = b[y<test_line] # assign below line to b
output[y==test_line] = ab_mean[y==test_line] # assign coords on line to "interpolation"
plt.imshow(output)
```

[image]

```
test_line = linfunc(x, -4, + 150) #  y = -4x + 150
output = np.zeros_like(a)
output[y>test_line] = a[y>test_line] # assign above line to a
output[y<test_line] = b[y<test_line] # assign below line to b
output[y==test_line] = ab_mean[y==test_line] # assign coords on line to "interpolation"
plt.imshow(output)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! One issue here is that you can't represent a straight vertical line (`m=inf`).

Comment: True, infinity is out of the picture. In a finite 100 by 100 grid, however, any slope >= 100 is effectively infinitely large. The bordering line can still be moved left and right, by adjusting the offset accordingly, so I don't see a fundamental limitation in writing a function that, given two points, returns a line equation.